# Bloco de código não tem tamanho limitado na página de revisão

Tags: bug, layout, interface-usuário, histórico-de-revisões

Parece que, quando o bloco de código é composto por linhas muito grandes, na página de revisão, ele não é corretamente ajustado.

Na página de revisão:

[image: Demonstração do problema. O bloco de código ultrapassa o "contêiner geral" da página.]

Note que (provavelmente por conta do bloco de código) as postagens nessa página de revisão acabam por ultrapassar o limite do "contêiner geral" da página (demarquei em vermelho). Para capturar a imagem tive que usar o *scroll* horizontal, o que não é algo muito comum e, por isso, creio que seja um bug. Só para referência, o cinza escuro no canto inferior esquerdo da imagem é o rodapé do site.

[Veja acontecendo aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/109546/revisions)

Nas perguntas isso não acontece.

Comment: Na verdade acho que não é bug não, é porque é o post original. Outros exemplos: [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/422460/revisions), [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/168715/revisions), [3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/168542/revisions) (é só procurar qualquer pergunta com edição)

Comment: @RafaelTavares, o código está "passando do tamanho" da minha tela, tive que usar o scroll horizontal para capturar a imagem acima. Pelo menos ao meu ver, não parece ser um comportamento esperado.

Comment: Ah sim, esqueci desse detalhe, interpretei a demarcação vermelha como metade da tela (metade para uma revisão, metade para outra). Ocupar mais do que 100% é bug sim com certeza hahaha

Comment: É, mas foi falta de esclarecer da minha parte também. O cinza escuro ali em baixo é o rodapé do site. Vou editar a pergunta para deixar mais claro, obrigado! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Um problema com a mesma causa foi reportado no [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361318/818993) e foi corrigido em Fev/2021, pelo [Brian Nickel ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/235711/brian-nickel). Abaixo trago algumas informações da resposta dele:

Aparentemente, antes era usado o elemento `<table>` na página, que tem certos problemas na estilização em relação ao `width` com flexbox. Então, publicações com um código muito longo (em uma única linha) causavam um *overflow* no eixo X.

Como a página tinha mais de um problema, ela foi inteiramente modificada para ficar responsiva, e agora não temos mais `<table>`s.